Does EMR Serverless support Bootstrap action
When EMR cluster is created, there is a provision to provide bootstrap actions as shown below.
aws emr create-cluster --name "Test cluster" --release-label emr-7.1.0 
--use-default-roles --ec2-attributes KeyName=myKey 
--applications Name=Hive Name=Pig 
--instance-count 3 --instance-type m5.xlarge 
--bootstrap-actions Path="s3://mybucket/myscriptfolder/copymyfile.sh"
Is there any option available in EMR Serverless?

No, unfortunately, Like EMR on EC2, EMR Serverless don't provide bootstrap-action option to execute post cluster spin-up custom scripts.
Instead, EMR Serverless supports building custom image on the exisiting base image provided by AWS and you can install the packages or pass additional configuration required.
The documentation to achieve this is available here and here
